# WinRT binding, UI does not Update

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a view model that loads some data. While loading a DependencyProperty is set to true, later false again. I've often done this in WPF, but with modern Apps it don't work. :(

The view that is bound to the model should shows if the model is still loading. It just shows the value when the Page is loaded, but doesn't updates the view after the value changes.

I've written a little example that uses SharedProjects for Phone, Modern App and WPF. ([BindingExample](http://1drv.ms/1HGfmys))

For test purpose it just switches between true and false.

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Loading, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The Constructor of the Page

```
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        var v = new Viewmodle();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = v;

        v.Test();
    }
```

The Viewmodle:

```
public class Viewmodle : DependencyObject
{

    public bool Loading
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(LoadingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadingProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Loading.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Loading", typeof(bool), typeof(Viewmodle), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public async void Test()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
            this.Loading = true;
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
            this.Loading = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want INotifyPropertyChanged instead of DependencyObject. The way you're binding right now is actually just a plain property binding, its not really using the DependencyProperty. This can be evidenced by removing the CLR property and only having the DependencyProperty registration. You will see the binding has failed at runtime. DependencyProperty binding is seemingly only useful when the source has originated in xaml. So instead of setting your view model in code the way you have you could have done something like this

```html
<Grid.Resources>
   <local:Viewmodle x:Name="viewModel"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=viewModel, Path=Loading}"/>
```

then you could call viewModel.Test() in your constructor to start your test using the xaml made view model